# While selecting 1 value it automatically selects other values in Listview in Android

Tags: android

I have a list view showing Music names and when I select 1 of the music Progress bar in it is visibled below it.Problem is when i click 1st it automatically also selects 4 and so on i.e for 2 it selects 5 3-8..
I think so when Adapter holds plenty of values it doesnt load all at a time it loads batchwise as screen is scrolled down,so when i select 1st item in batch 1 it also selects 1st item of preceeding batches.
Here is the code :

```
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // here we inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.music_videos_sublayout, null);

        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }

        if (mediaflag == 1) {
            ImageView media_image = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.media_type);
            media_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.video);
        } else {
            ImageView media_image = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.media_type);
            media_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.music);
        }

        ImageView club_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.clubimage_music_videos_sublayout);

        TextView club_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.clubname_music_videos_sublayout);           
        club_name.setText(mediaArraylist.get(position).getClubName());

        TextView mediaName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.songname_music_videos_sublayout);
        mediaName.setText(mediaArraylist.get(position).getMedianame());

        AQuery aQuery = new AQuery(MusicVideosActivity.this);

        String thumbnail = mediaArraylist.get(position).getClubimage();
        Bitmap preset = aQuery.getCachedImage(thumbnail);

        club_image.setImageBitmap(preset);


        v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View myView) {

                System.out.println("Clicked within View"+position);
                ProgressBar musicBar1 = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                musicBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });     

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: have you set listview select mode to single?

Answer (score 0):

use the bin and set the boolean variable as isAvail in getview put this line...

```
musicbar1.setVisibility(listitem.isAvail() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```